# What exactly does mapping do in Elasticsearch?

Tags: python, json, elasticsearch

I've been working with Elasticsearch for the last three weeks. I came across the concept of mapping. I've done mapping on "lat" and "long" fields in my RESTful JSON data. Here is my mapping ( ES with python client):

```
settings = { "settings": {
                 "number_of_shards":1,
                  'number_of_replicas':0
                 },
      "mappings" : { 
           "document" : {
                "properties":{
                    "geo": {
                       "type": "geo_point"
                            }
                          }
                        } 
                     } 
                  }

es.indices.create(index = "myindex", body=settings)
es.index(index='myindex', doc_type='document', body=new_data)
```

This will create a new filed called "geo" in my data. (Please correct me if I'm wrong)
But I've seen it (in some examples) to be as shown bellow:

```
 settings = { "settings": {
                 "number_of_shards":1,
                  'number_of_replicas':0
                 },
             "mappings": {
    "document": {
        "properties": {
            "id": {"type" : "long"},
            "version": {"type" : "text"},
            "timestamp": {"type" : "long"},
            "changeset": {"type" : "long"},
            "uid" : {"type" : "long"},
            "user_sid" : {"type" : "string"},
            "location": {"type": "geo_point"}
            }
        }
    }
  }
```

I don't understand the difference between them. Also, some people are talking about dynamic mapping, default mapping which confuses me. Can someone explain this to me?

Comment: Mapping is how you define the types of your fields, if they are strings or numbers for example, dynamic mapping is basically when you don't map every field you will receive and allows elasticsearch to do the mapping. The [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping.html#mapping) is pretty on point, take a look of the data types and what is the difference between them.

Comment: Define your field types (int, String, etc...) to be able to search by them.
The  ES documentation is great on that matter: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/mapping.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**what is mapping?**

Its basically defining data type of each field.
Just like in Mysql you define data type for each columns. (int, float, text)

**what is dynamic mapping?**

 Mysql you need to have a fixed schema. you can not insert a data to a column unless its predefined.

 Elasticsearch is schemaless. you can insert a data to a field that does not exis

Elasticsearch will figure out the data type for you create mappings automatically